Japa counting, 10 onwards, using fingers and beads
I have heard two different views on Japa counting using palm/fingers. There is consistency in counting 1-10 (from middle node of Anamika, and finish at Tarjani bottom node). But I see differing views on counting the 11th onwards.
One such view of 11-20 counting is as shown in the image here. It is reverse of 1-10. So, 1-10 in clockwise, 11-20 in anti-clockwise, and so it goes.
Another view is after reaching the count of 10, one should return and start again at middle node of Anamika. I.e., Japa count #1 and #11, #21, etc. all start and finish at same point. After reaching 10, 20, 30,... one should bring back the counting finger to 1 using the same route (without crossing Meru, Madhyama node). During this cross period (may be a fraction of second time), one should not do Japa, because it is apradikashana. [this view is expressed in this video; it is in Kannada but I have explained his method above.]
It is stated (in the same video) that while Japa maala (beads) as well one should not do reverse and instead return back to original position and the resume Japa. I have also seen some saying is reversed (so that count resumes in clockwise direction) when we reach Meru.
Which is the right method - for counting using fingers and mala?


This is a good question but unnecessarily being downvoted.
